# Variable outside for /f command keeps getting reset

Tags: batch-file

In the following code, it seems that the `set /A lcnt=3` at the top of the file is executed each time that the for /f command just below the `REM #1` is executed.

I guess I don't understand the flow of execution.  I thought it just runs from top to bottom, barring any gotos.

My script:

```
echo off

REm     Why is the following set command executed each time
REM     in the below "processToken section"? 

set /A lcnt=3

cd c:\download

REM         ___ input file _____
REm         Moe Larry Curly 
REM         Manny Moe Jack 

REM         ___ echo output ____
REM         4
REM         3
REM         5
REM         4
REM         6
REM         5
REM         4
REM         3
REM         5
REM         4
REM         6
REM         5

REm #1

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%f in ('type test_list.txt') do (
  set line=%%f
  call :processToken
   )
pause
  goto :eof

:processToken
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 
  for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%a in ("%line%") do (
    set /A lcnt+=1

    echo !lcnt!
    echo %lcnt% 

    set line=%%b
  )
  if not "%line%" == "" goto :processToken
  goto :eof

pause
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour to this site.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) Especially, learn how to use the editor to fix your markdown.

Comment: Never do a `cd drive:\path`. This will *not* change your drive. Always put two commands like that `c:` and `cd \path`.

Comment: `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` will create a *local* environment that is *closed* upon leaving the block at `:eof`, therefore all changes to variables within `:processToken` are *not* seen by the caller.

Comment: @yacc that is what the /D option is for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve because your question does not provide that information.

Here therefore is some example code which may help:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "x=0"
For /F "UseBackQDelims=" %%A in ("C:\download\test_list.txt") Do (Set/A x+=1
    Set "y=0"
    For %%B In (%%A) Do (Set/A y+=1
        Set "line!x!str!y!=%%~B")
    Echo line!x! has !y! space separated strings)
Set line 2>Nul
Pause
```

Comment: The question is in the first 2 REm lines.  I was raised a COBOL programmer, and I don't understand how lcnt is reinitialized to 3 each time processToken is entered.  If I could understand that, it will help me become a better programmer.